# full screen responsive background image

Tags: css, image, background, frontend

the background image not appear as full image on large screen but , it's fit on small screen .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" dir="ltr" />
    <title></title>

    <style>

     
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .bgImage {
            /* The image used */
            background: url(../../../Content/imgs/common/myimage.png) no-repeat center ;
            height: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
        }
       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bgImage">
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

there's a specific dimension for image to work as responsive on all screens ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `background-position:center`
`background-attachment:fixed`  to your bgimage class